# How to show a mapping T is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra

I must show that $T :\mathbb{R}^2→\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T(x, y)=(x + y, x)$;

I know that a mapping is linear if:

> (1) $T(x+y) = T(x)+T(y)$

and

> (2) $T(\lambda x) = \lambda T(x)$

or

> (3) $T(\lambda x + \rho y) = \lambda T(x) + \rho T(y)$

I don't know how to implement (3).

Comment: 1 & 2.are easier to check and sufficient. No need for 3.

Comment: Also you have (4) $T(\lambda x +  y) = \lambda T(x) +  T(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(\lambda(x,y))=T(\lambda x,\lambda y)=(\lambda x+\lambda y,\lambda x)=\lambda(x+y,x)=\lambda T(x,y)$

and also

$T((a,b)+(x,y))=T((a+x,b+y))=(a+b+x+y,a+x)=(a+b,a)+(x+y,x)=T((a,b))+T((x,y))$

So (1) and (2) are satisfied and this concludes that the mapping is linear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a misunderstanding because of bad notation! :)

It is better to denote your linearity properties as

$$\eqalign{
  & T\left( {{\bf{x}} + {\bf{y}}} \right){\rm{ }} = {\rm{ }}T\left( {\bf{x}} \right) + T\left( {\bf{y}} \right)  \cr 
  & T(\lambda {\bf{x}}) = \lambda T({\bf{x}}) \cr} $$

where $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ are vectors not scalars!

Now, in your example ${\bf{x}} = (x,y)$.

Comment: @b.vasquez: Take a look at this. I think this was your main source of confusion! :)